# Differentiation and Rate of Change

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Im slaving over this one
using rate of change and Differentiation

I tried the chain rule but that is not the route as it got passed back

Question: find rate of change v if

V = x^3 * y^2
where
x=cos3t and y =sin3t

which gives
v = cos^3(3t) * sin^2(3t)

This is what i have so far 
dv/dx
3-3Sin3t^2 x Sin3t^2

-9sin3t^2 x Sin3t^2

-9Sin3t^4

dv/dy
cos3t^3 x 2x3Cos3t

Cos3t^3 x 6Cos3t

6Cos3t^4

so

v = -9Sin3t^4 + 6Cos3t^4

but get the feeling that the "product rule" changes my calculations further.

im a bit stuck, can any one give some advice or confirm my calcs ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since $x=\cos 3t$ and $y = \sin 3t$, by chain rule we have:
$$
\dfrac{dx}{dt} = -3 \sin 3t \qquad \text{and} \qquad \dfrac{dy}{dt} = 3 \cos 3t
$$
Hence, by product rule, we have:
$$ \begin{align*}
\dfrac{dV}{dt}
&= \left(3x^2 \dfrac{dx}{dt}\right)(y^2) + (x^3)\left(2y \dfrac{dy}{dt}\right) \\
&= (3\cos^2 3t) (-3 \sin 3t)(\sin^2 3t) + (\cos^3 3t)(2 \sin 3t) (3 \cos 3t) \\
&= -9\cos^2 3t\sin^2 3t\sin 3t + 6\cos^3 3t\cos 3t\sin 3t \\
\end{align*} $$

Comment: Man that was fast

Thanks you for the fast responce, Im a part time HND student (bit older than most) and im having trouble with the product rule.

To help out, could you give any explaination of one half so i can work through the other myself
<br>
im having an issue with this bit
(3cos 2 3t)(−3sin3t)(sin 2 3t)

i know i need to differentiate but it seems to have been done twice

Thanks in advance 

DB

Comment: @user83327 Since $x=\cos 3t$, we have $3x^2 = 3\cos^2 3t$. Next, I substitute $dx/dt = -3\sin 3t$. Finally, since $y = \sin 3t$, we have $y^2 = \sin^2 3t$.

Comment: Great I will go through this tonight, This was very usefull thankyou, mark as compleete or usefull ?

Comment: Excellent, Looked at the product rule behaviour and see how we Diff the variable after inserting it, Thanks for your Help. DB